# how to support the app distribution of apk for devices that are not in google playstore supported list

Tags: android

Developed an app that supports minimum android version Kitkat and maximum is Marshmallow. i deployed the app on google playstore and i was able to download it on devices supporting android versions kitkat to Marshmallow. i recently got Vodafone smartTab II 3g, this has android Marshmallow in it. This device is not able to download the app from the playtore. when was downloaded from my mail it was able it install the app and run it successfully. 
When i crosschecked on supported devices on the google playstore. The supported devices list does not have Vodafone smartTab II 3g. can someone help me out how can i make the app supported for this device?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have some other declaration in the Android Manifest that requires a feature the tablet doesn't have. For instance, do you have any `uses-feature` lines?

Comment: manifest file has  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't have auto focus?  That seems unlikely though. There must be something else in the manifest that it doesn't support...

Comment: For instance, does the Manifest have a '<compatible-screens>' statement? See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: @bremen_batt No, there is no <compatible-screens> defined in the Manifest

Comment: I am not sure what you can do here. My guess would be that the device manufacturer forgot to list auto focus in the device description, and so the play store is not letting you download it. I would contact Vodafone support. This seems to me like a bug on their end.

Comment: When you use the camera, the device does auto focus....right? For instance, most camera apps, when you touch the screen, you will see it refocus.